# Downloading files from Web using basic URL Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, basic-authentication, webclient

I can successfully download a file using the following link in a browser:

https://userbob:qwerty@assoc-datafeeds-na.amazon.com/datafeed/getReport?filename=feedreport-1265.xml.gz

Now I need to to do this in my C# application.

**Solution 1**: using WebClient

```
        string url = $"https://assoc-datafeeds-na.amazon.com/datafeed/getReport?filename=feedreport-1265.xml.gz";


        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string authInfo =Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("userbob:qwerty"));
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authInfo;
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/octet-stream";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";

            var data = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        }
```

DownloadData throws an exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

**Solution 2:** using WebRequest

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        string authInfo =Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("userbob:qwerty"));

        ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        var response = request.GetResponse();
```

The same exception on the last line. I feel I am missing some header or setting to fully mimic browser behavior.

Interestingly, if I omit Authorization header in either of the solutions, I get 401:Unauthorized exceptions. That makes me think that I pass authorization and the problem is in something else. What am I missing ?

Comment: Do you get the same exception if you attempt to login with incorrect credentials? If you don't, and you get _500_ again, then it is most likely something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass token by converting to Base64:

```
var username = "xxxxxxx";
var password = "yyyyyyy";
var token = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
```